# Error 403 Acesso Proibido

Tags: xampp

Estou utilizando o Xampp e virtual host , já segui um tutorial da internet e mesmo assim ainda recebo este erro 403.Já configurei os arquivos httpd.conf e httpd-vhosts.conf e não sei o que pode ser.Alguém saberia o que pode estar faltando?

Comment: Esse erro significa que você não tem permissões para acessar determinado servidor. Esse erro se dá basicamente através de: Permissões de arquivos ou pastas incorretas ou por configurações incorretas em seu arquivo .htaccess

Comment: ok obrigado pela ajuda vou rever aqui alguns arquivos se estão sem permissão deve ser isso

Comment: @Danilo qual foi a solução para esse problema?